# Rending partial from Ajax response is not updating variable

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a Rails partial I am attempting to populate and display based on a Ajax response but it seems the instance variable is not being updated.  I know I'm missing something.

It might be due to the fact that I'm using a different controller for the view than the ajax call.

When my view instantiates, I provide a value for `@ingredients` or else my partial throws an error:

```
# RecipesController#new
def new
  @recipe = Recipe.new
  @ingredients = []
end
```

Here's the ajax function that is called when the user clicks a button:

```
$('.ingredientContainer').on('click', '.searchForIngredient', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const ingredientName = $(this).parents('fieldset').find('.ingredient-item').val()
    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/ingredients/search',
        data: {
            name: ingredientName
        },
        success: (res) => {
            // This displays the correct response
            console.log("res", res)

            // This prints [] as if @ingredients has not changed
            console.log("<%= @ingredients %>")

            $('.ingredientSelectionModalBody').html("<%= j(render partial: 'ingredient_search_table', locals: {ingredient_array: @ingredients}) %>")
            $('.ingredientModal').modal({show: true})
        }
    })
})
```

Here's the `IngredientsController` that is called from the Ajax request and where I expect to define the value of `@ingredients`:

```
class IngredientsController < ApplicationController
    def search
        @ingredients = Tools.searchForIngredient(params['name'])
    end
end
```

Here's my partial that is rendered into a modal's body:

```
<table class="table table-awaken">
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Brand</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <%= ingredient_array.inspect %>
            <% ingredient_array.each do |ingredient| %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= ingredient.name %></td>
                    <td><%= ingredient.brand %></td>
                    <td><%= ingredient.description %></td>
                </tr>
            <% end -%>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The issue is that the view is not aware the value of `@ingredients` has been updated and I'm not sure how to fix that so that the response from `IngredientsController` can be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The `console.log("<%= @ingredients %>")` is from the JS viewpoint hardcoded as `console.log("[]")` when the page is initially rendered. You can check it if you inspect the page and find the code in the loaded assets.

The get the actual data you have to return it as a response to the `/ingredients/search` call. Make the request of type `application/json` and return something like `render json: @ingredients` from your controller. Then on the frontend you should have these data in the `res` variable so use that instead of `<%= @ingredients %>`

Comment: How am I supposed to render a rails partial using a javascript variable?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by moving the DOM modification javascript into the file being rendered by the `IngredientsController`.  I generated a file `search.js.erb` with the following content:

```
$('.ingredientSelectionModalBody').html("<%= j(render 'recipes/ingredient_search_table', ingredient_array: @ingredients) %>")
$('.ingredientModal').modal({show: true})
```

Since this is rendered after `@ingredients` has been updated, the new data from the controller is available.